# Video Modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem, have been a few days being employed at a web page for a few friends, and I need to do the modal one with a video of YouTube, am using swig for that it seems to me that compiled to html is very effective, an overcoat when you use objects as JSON, the question is that I have managed to make the modal one with images, is very simple, but with the videos it is more complicated.

this is my css:

```
  #headerLogo{
    background: url(https://images2.alphacoders.com/698/698137.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    height: 250px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  #text{
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 36px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 250px;
  }
  .navbar{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .fa{
    font-size:22px;
    color: #0077cd;
  }
  .fa:hover{
    color: #0890f2;
  }
  .footer{
    text-align: center;
    color: #c6c6c6;
  }
  #indexImage{
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  #myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)}
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

This is my js file:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("imageClass");
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    var img = images[i];
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    img.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        modalImg.alt = this.alt;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
}
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
$('#closeImage').onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

And this is my projects.html made it with swig:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}
{% block header %}{% include 'header.html' %}{% endblock %}
{% block headerLogo %}{% include 'headerLogo.html' %}{% endblock %}
{% block styles %}{% include 'styles.html' %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

  <div>
    {% for key, val in projectImages %}
      {% if val.type == "image" %}
        <img id="myImg" class="imageClass" src="{{val.src}}" alt="{{val.title}}" width="300" height="200">
      {% elseif val.type == "video" %}
        <img id="myImg" class="videoClass" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/{{val.src}}/0.jpg" alt="{{val.title}}" width="300" height="200">
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span id="closeImage" class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="../js/fotoInModal.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

My JSON object:

```
{
  "title": "Argochamber",
  "indexContent":"Was created in 2012, by Pablo Blanco Celdrán and Eric Dacal Sanchez, in order to create fun games and for the whole world.",
  "navButtons" : [{"name": "Projects", "src": "./projects.html"}, {"name": "Contacts", "src": "./contacts.html"},{"name": "Teams", "src":"./teams.html"}],
  "imageUrl" : "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/17063359?v=4&s=200",
  "imageHeaderLogo" : "https://images2.alphacoders.com/698/698137.jpg",
  "headerNavBar": "navbar-light bg-primary",
  "fontawesome": [{"icon": "fa fa-facebook-official", "src": "https://www.facebook.com/argochamber/?ref=br_rs"},
  {"icon": "fa fa-twitter-square", "src": "https://twitter.com/argochamber"}],
  "projectImages":[{"title": "Spiderman in New York", "src": "../image/spidey.jpg", "type": "image"},
  {"title": "Sculpting link", "src":"ALbt17LLH54", "type": "video"}],
  "css": {
    "headerTextColor": "white",
    "headerFontSize": "36px"
  }
}
```

Result before click image:
[image: Result before modal]

Result after click image:
[image: Result after click image]

Comment: Not certain what issue is?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

In `projects.html` you have `img` instead of YouTube `iframe`

```
{% elseif val.type == "video" %}
        <img id="myImg" class="videoClass" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/{{val.src}}/0.jpg" alt="{{val.title}}" width="300" height="200">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yes, because i want a picture of youtube video.